# Locate phone with Find My iPhone without locking it

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Can you use the Find My iPhone app without it locking the phone your trying to find? I only want the location, not to lock it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure - so long as the phone can currently find a net connection.

Either from another iPhone, using the Find my iPhone app & entering your own Apple ID, or from the website - https://www.icloud.com/#find

It will show on the map & give you options to Play Sound - useful if it's somewhere near you, down the back of the sofa, in a coat pocket etc, or more seriously if it's been stolen or lost you can set Lost Mode or Wipe all data.